# JSON Serialisation Inherited List Class Property Not Serialised

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following Interface and class structure

```
public class RefreshCostResult : IRefreshCostResults
    {
        #region IRefreshCostResults Members

        public TimeSpan TimeToCompletion
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ApplicationLocation
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Enums.RefreshCostStatus ApplicationResult
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class RefreshCostItems : List<IRefreshCostResults>, IRefreshCostItems
    {
        public TimeSpan TotalTimeTaken
        {
            get
            {
                var tsTotal = (from x in this
                               select x.TimeToCompletion).Sum(x => x.TotalMilliseconds);
                return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tsTotal);
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my controller action i am returning a JSON string via the following function

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RefreshCostOnProject(int projectID, int userId)
{
    var result = new RefreshCostItems();
    result.Add(new RefreshCostResult
    {
        ApplicationLocation = "FOO",
        TimeToCompletion = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(22),
        ApplicationResult = RefreshCostStatus.Success
    });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

But when I call the function and the result is returned the Property `TotalTimeTaken` is not serialised.
the returned JSON is

```
[{
        "TimeToCompletion" : {
            "Hours" : 0,
            "Minutes" : 22,
            "Seconds" : 0,
            "Milliseconds" : 0,
            "Ticks" : 13200000000,
            "Days" : 0,
            "TotalDays" : 0.015277777777777777,
            "TotalHours" : 0.36666666666666664,
            "TotalMilliseconds" : 1320000,
            "TotalMinutes" : 22,
            "TotalSeconds" : 1320
        },
        "ApplicationLocation" : "FOO",
        "ApplicationResult" : 1
    }
]
```

Is there something I am missing? I have attached a debugger and the property is not getting called on serialisation.

Comment: You do realize that namespaces don't have to be fully qualified? Especially in a sample code for SO question, where it becomes pure noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not inherit from `List<T>`. JSON serializers serialize collections as JSON arrays. And arrays can't have properties by definition.

Replace inheritance with encapsulation:

```
class RefreshCostItems
{
    public List<RefreshCostResult> Items { ... }
    public TimeSpan TotalTimeTaken { ... }
}
```